# Does memcpy recognize the underlying size of the destination?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint8_t a = 1;
    uint16_t b = 0;

    memcpy(&b, &a, 1);

    cout << bitset<16>(b) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is `0000000000000001`. I, however, would expect `memcpy` to just copy `a` into the first byte of `b` and `b` to be `0000000100000000` instead. What happens here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`memcpy` takes a `void *` for each argument, so it has no information about the types of the underlying variables.  It copies exactly the number of bytes specified.

The reason you see `0x0001` instead of `0x0100` is probably because your system uses little endian byte ordering, which means that the least significant byte comes first.

Comment: To note, pretty much any desktop system uses little endian nowadays, so not like it's a quirk.

Comment: So technically the output is UB?

Comment: @Valentin Good question. The output is implementation defined if not UB. Someone will probably have to go diving into the C++ Standard (or have some sort of pornographic memory) to get the exact answer.

Comment: Do Apple desktops use little endian?  My last understanding was the Apple was using Big Endian processors.

Comment: @KillzoneKid `bitset` is safe, but the trick Asker is using to load the `uint16_t` being used as the source of the `bitset` is vulnerable to byte order. I'm not sure if that is UB or not.

Comment: @user4581301 Looking at the source code of memcpy, it takes pointer to destination and copies source byte by byte, starting in both cases from the beginning. So on big-endian system the 1st and 2nd byte would be swapped and such copy will produce 256 instead of 1, so looks like UB

Comment: @ThomasMatthews in the past yes, Macs have been x86 for a decade now

Answer (score 0):

No, `memcpy` doesn't know anything about the sizes of the buffers, that's why
you have to pass the number of bytes you want to copy. Whether the buffers are
large enough, is not of `memcpy`'s concern.

You only copy **1** byte, only the least significant byte is copied in `b`,
that's why you see a `0000000000000001`.